# iOs After Launch Screen is loaded black screen

Tags: ios, xcode11, swift5

Hey I hope someone can help me.

So far I've only done the User interface of a multiview app, no coding done.
And I wanted to check it in the simulator.
Now, the launch Screen loads correctly, but then the screen goes black instead of showing the first view controller. And nothing in the debugger.

-Edit: After editing the info.plist, I do now get an error in the debugger
regarding to a missing SceneDelegate. 
[image: mainStoryboard]

[image: sceneDelegate]
[info.plist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nAqzl.png)

Comment: The problem is that your Info.plist is wrong. You started to add multiple window support but you never finished. So your Scene Configuration is empty.

Comment: @matt thank you, so I  guess a have to add something with the (+) at "scene Configuration" in my info.plist. Is there a specific name or kind I have to enter?

Comment: Yes there is. That’s the issue here. Start with a new project to see what the Info.plist needs to look like.

Comment: Well it didn't solve my problem so far. But at least now I get some hints in the debugger, regarding to a missing SceneDelegate.

Answer (score -2):

You have to set Main Storyboard  from Project general tab.

`General -> Main Interface`